# Calculating the points of tangency for two circles given a picture

Tags: geometry, circles

I have two circles with the same radius and I want to calculate the points of tangency.

For example, in the picture below, I want to calculate $(x_3, y_3)$ and $(x_4,y_4)$. I have the radius and the distance between the two circles as shown below:

[image]

Comment: A tangent and a radius to a circle at any point are perpendicular.  You might find that fact helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of the tangent to any circle is given by $$-\frac{(x'-a)}{(y'-b)}$$ Where (x',y') is the point of tangency and (a,b) is the center of the circle. Now the gradient of the line joining the centers of the two circles is same as the gradient of the tangent. Hence in this case this essentially translates to the following equation $$ -\frac{(x_3-x_1)}{(y_3-y_1)}=\frac{(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)}$$ The other equation is $$ (x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2= R^2$$ Solving the above two equations you will get two points for $(x_3,y_3)$. This shows the existence of two parallel tangents. Similarly you can solve for $(x_4,y_4)$

Comment: ?thanks,it seems great,i didnt understand about (a,b) this the center point of which circle?

Comment: This is the center of the circle to which you are drawing the tangent. In your case you can take it as $(x_1,y_1) or (x_2,y_2)$. But then the equation of the circle should be consistent. I have edited my comments and removed the ambiguity.

Comment: thanks,in the first equation i have x1,x2,y1,y2.i can use just this equation to calculate x3,y3 and x4,y4 .so why should i use second equation?thanks so much

Comment: If you do get the correct answer, it is alright. But just double check before you conclude.

Comment: thanks so much for your help

Comment: you are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
y_3 = y_1 + R \cos \theta \\
x_3= x_1 + R \sin \theta \\
y_4= y_2 +R \cos \theta \\
x_4 = x_2 +R \sin \theta \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: thanks but i dont know the value of theta

Comment: If you have only the radius and the distance between the circles. I do not think is possible to find points.

Comment: If this is a problem in coordinate geometry, you may know the coordinaes of the centres. And knowing the radius and the distance between centres, you know the trig functions of the little angle at $(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: can i calculate hypotenuse of below triangle with Pythagorean formula and then calculate lengh of tangent line(again using Pythagorean) and then calculate (x3,y3) and (x4,y4) ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas:i did not understand what you said

Comment: @Arash: Do not have time to write out a solution. Length of tangent line is already given.

Comment: no,i dont have Length of tangent line